# Interface covariance contravariance : why is this not compiling?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, covariance, contravariance

I want to implement a `CommandBus` that can `Dispatch` some `Commands` to `CommandHandlers`.

- A `Command` is a simple a DTO describing what should happen. For instance : "Increment counter by 5"
- A `CommandHandler` is able to handle a precise type of `Command`.
- The `CommandBus` takes a `Command` and executes the `CommandHandler` that is able to handle it.

The code I wrote does not compile.

Compiler complains `cannot convert from 'IncrementHandler' to 'Handler<Command>'`.
I don't understand why, because `IncrementHandler` implements `Handler<Increment>` and `Increment` implements `Command`

I've tried both `in` and `out` modifiers on the generic interfaces, it doesn't solve the problem.

Is there a way to achieve this with only interfaces ?

```
[TestClass]
public class CommandBusTest
{
  [TestMethod]
  public void DispatchesProperly()
  {
    var handler = new IncrementHandler(counter: 0);
    var bus = new CommandBus(handler); // <--Doesn't compile: cannot convert from 'IncrementHandler' to 'Handler<Command>'
    bus.Dispatch(new Increment(5));
    Assert.AreEqual(5, handler.Counter);
  }
}

public class CommandBus
{
  private readonly Dictionary<Type, Handler<Command>> handlers;

  public CommandBus(params Handler<Command>[] handlers)
  {
    this.handlers = handlers.ToDictionary(
      h => h.HandledCommand,
      h => h);
  }

  public void Dispatch(Command commande) { /*...*/ }
}

public interface Command { }

public interface Handler<TCommand> where TCommand : Command
{
  Type HandledCommand { get; }
  void Handle(TCommand command);
}

public class Increment : Command
{
  public Increment(int value) { Value = value; }

  public int Value { get; }
}

public class IncrementHandler : Handler<Increment>
{
  // Handler<Increment>
  public Type HandledCommand => typeof(Increment);
  public void Handle(Increment command)
  {
    Counter += command.Value;
  }
  // Handler<Increment>

  public int Counter { get; private set; }

  public IncrementHandler(int counter)
  {
    Counter = counter;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why your are passing an array.  Have you tried:public CommandBus(Handler<Command> handlers)
  {
    this.handlers = handlers.ToDictionary(
      h => h.HandledCommand,
      h => h);
  }

Comment: I used `params` because I want to be able to pass as many Handlers as I want, like so : `new CommandBus(new AHander(), new BHandler(), new CHandler())`
The bus will contain several Handlers, because there will be several types of Command.

Comment: the `params` syntax is fine, it will appear as a `Handler<Command>[]` with one entry in the constructor.

Comment: Given the definition of `Handler<TCommand>` you can only make it contravariant in `TCommand` but then `IncrementHandler` is not compatible with `Handler<Command>` since `Command` is a supertype of `Increment` and not a subtype as required. There's no way to do this safely so you'll have to cast somewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I don't understand why, because `IncrementHandler` implements `Handler<Increment>` and `Increment` implements `Command`

Let's fix your misunderstanding, and then the rest will become clear.

Suppose what you wanted to do was legal. What goes wrong?

```
IncrementHandler ih = whatever;
Handler<Command> h = ih; // This is illegal. Suppose it is legal.
```

now we make a class

```
public class Decrement : Command { ... }
```

And now we pass it to h:

```
Decrement d = new Decrement();
h.Handle(d);
```

This is legal, because `Handler<Command>.Handle` takes a `Command`, and a `Decrement` is a `Command`.

So what happened? You just passed a decrement command to `ih`, via `h`, but `ih` is an `IncrementHandler` that only knows how to handle increments.

Since that is nonsensical, *something* in here has to be illegal; which line would you like to be illegal?  The C# team decided that the conversion is the thing that should be illegal.

More specifically:

**Your program is using reflection in an attempted end-run around the type system's safety checks, and then you are complaining that the type system is stopping you when you write something unsafe**. Why are you using generics *at all*?

Generics are (in part) to ensure type safety, and then you are doing a *dispatch based on reflection*. This doesn't make any sense; don't take steps to increase type safety *and then do heroic efforts to work around them*.

Plainly you wish to work around type safety, so *don't use generics at all*. Just make an `ICommand` interface and a `Handler` class that takes a command, and then have some mechanism for working out how to dispatch commands.

What I don't understand though is why there are two kinds of things at all. If you want to execute a command, then why not simply put the execution logic on the command object?

There are also other design patterns you could use here other than this clunky dictionary lookup based on types. For example:

- a command handler could have a method that takes a command and returns a boolean, whether the handler can handle this command or not.  Now you have a list of command handlers, a command comes in, and you just run down the list asking "are you my handler?" until you find one.  If O(n) lookup is too slow, then build a MRU cache or memoize the result or some such thing, and the amortized behaviour will improve.
- the dispatch logic could be put into the command handler itself. A command handler is given a command; it either executes it, or it recurses, calling its parent command handler. You can thus build a graph of command handlers that defer work to each other as necessary.  (This is basically how QueryService works in COM.)

Comment: Typical - I use a couple hundred words to try to explain something, and then Eric Lippert comes along and explains it better in 5 lines of code. ;)

Comment: Thanks Eric. At the time of writing I was thinking you might show up and answer :) You make good points on the possible enhancements of the pattern I'm using. This code was about implementing a version of CQRS that I was told about at a recent meetup. So I gave a go at the proposed design and faced the compilation issue. I think it's a smell that I should change something. I'll look into that!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `Increment` implements `Command` (which I renamed to `ICommand` to make that clearer, in the code below).
So it is no longer accepted as a `Handler<Command>`, which is what the constructor expects (subtype instead of required supertype, as @Lee pointed out in comments).

If you can generalize to use just `ICommand`, it would work:

```
public class CommandBusTest
{
    public void DispatchesProperly()
    {
        var handler = new IncrementHandler(counter: 0);
        var bus = new CommandBus((IHandler<ICommand>)handler); 
        bus.Dispatch(new Increment(5));
    }
}

public class CommandBus
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, IHandler<ICommand>> handlers;

    public CommandBus(params IHandler<ICommand>[] handlers)
    {
        this.handlers = handlers.ToDictionary(
          h => h.HandledCommand,
          h => h);
    }

    public void Dispatch(ICommand commande) { /*...*/ }
}

public interface ICommand { int Value { get; } }

public interface IHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
{
    Type HandledCommand { get; }
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}

public class Increment : ICommand
{
    public Increment(int value) { Value = value; }

    public int Value { get; }
}

public class IncrementHandler : IHandler<ICommand>
{
    // Handler<ICommand>
    public Type HandledCommand => typeof(Increment);

    public void Handle(ICommand command)
    {
        Counter += command.Value;
    }

    // Handler<ICommand>

    public int Counter { get; private set; }

    public IncrementHandler(int counter)
    {
        Counter = counter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your definition of `Handler<TCommand>` requires `TCommand` to be both covariant *and* contravariant - and that's not allowed.

To pass a `Handler<Increment>` into the constructor of `CommandBus` (which expects a `Handler<Command>`), you must declare `Command` as a covariant type parameter in `Handler`, like this:

```
public interface Handler<out TCommand> where TCommand : Command
```

Making this change allows you to pass in a `Handler<AnythingThatImplementsCommand>` wherever a `Handler<Command>` is requested, so your constructor for `CommandBus` works now.

But this introduces a new issue for the following line:

```
void Handle(TCommand command);
```

Since `TCommand` is covariant, it is possible to assign a `Handler<Increment>` to a `Handler<Command>` reference.  Then you would be able to call the `Handle` method but pass in *anything* that implements `Command` - clearly that's not going to work.  To make *this* call correct, you have to allow `TCommand` to be *contravariant* instead.

Since you can't do both, you'll have to make a concession somewhere.  One way to do this is by making using covariance in `Handler<TCommand>`, but force an explicit cast in your `Handle` method, like this:

```
public interface Handler<out TCommand> where TCommand : Command
{
    Type HandledCommand { get; }
    void Handle(Command command);
}

public class IncrementHandler : Handler<Increment>
{
    public void Handle(Command command)
    {
        Counter += ((Increment)command).Value;
    }
}
```

It doesn't prevent somebody from creating an `IncrementHandler` and then passing in the wrong kind of `Command`, but if the handlers are only used by `CommandBus` you can check the type in `CommandBus.Dispatch` and have something resembling type safety.